# SailsJS service call

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am building my first service. Is there something wrong with this code, cause I can see that user has been inserted in database but my code does not get to `res.json`.

My service

```
create: function(data) {
  return User.create(data);
}
```

My controller

```
UserService.create(req.params.all())
  .then(function(err, user) {
    if (err) return err;
    res.json(user);
  });
```

---

Updated code:

My service

```
create: function(data) {
  return User.create(data);
},
```

My controller

```
UserService.create(req.params.all())
  .then(function(user) {
    res.json(user);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    return res.negotiate(err);
  });
```

This gives me following error:

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: TypeError: this.toObject is not a function at [object Object].module.exports.attributes.toJSON (.../api/models/User.js:47:23) ...
```

Clearly I mixing things up. I don't know when to use promise, when callback, when return. Could anybody explain to me?

---

Updated code:

This is block when error is triggered. If I remove this block, code is working.

```
// Removing password from output
toJSON: () => {
  var data = this.toObject();
  delete data.password;

  return data;
},
```

Comment: Do you use Waterline?

Comment: Weellll don't keep us in suspense, what's on `api/models/User.js` line 47?  In fact, maybe just post the whole method that contains line 47.

Comment: As far as when to use promises or callbacks, they are simply two different styles of coding in Javascript.  You can use either, but not at the same time.  So, `User.create(...).then(...).catch(...)` or `User.create(...).exec(...)`, but not a mixture of the two.  The return statements don't mean much in the callback style, but are good practice to avoid accidentally running code after you intended for the function to be done.  With promises, you're technically supposed to return a value inside of every handler (every `then`, `catch`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have updated code above. But this is some kind of different issue, not concerning my first question. But if you have the answer, I am willing to listen :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're mixing promise and callback syntax.  When using `.then()`, you only need to use the first argument:

```
UserService.create(req.params.all())
  .then(function(user) {
    res.json(user);
  });
```

because to catch errors, you use `.catch()`:

```
UserService.create(req.params.all())
  .then(function(user) {
    res.json(user);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    return res.negotiate(err);
  });
```

If you want to use the two-argument callback style, use `.exec()` instead:

```
UserService.create(req.params.all())
  .exec(function(err, user) {
    if (err) {return res.negotiate(err);}
    res.json(user);
  });
```

Either way, you should never just `return` from a controller action; it should always terminate in a response of some kind (for errors, use `res.negotiate`, `res.serverError`, `res.badRequest`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I think "this" is already an object, so no need for toObject(). This is what worked for me:

```
toJSON: () => {
  delete this.password;
  return this;
},
```